# Evaluating: $\int \frac{t}{\cos{t}} dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

How would you evaluate the following indefinite integral? In fact, I did evaluate 
$\int \frac{\cos{t}}{t} dt$ by parametric integration and then I thought of this variant.
$$\int \frac{t}{\cos{t}} dt$$

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20t/cos%28t%29) you may find the result given by W|A.

Comment: Did you evaluated the primitive of $\cos t/t$?

Comment: @enzotib, that's actually easier, since it's just the cosine integral. This one will require the [inverse tangent integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html).

Comment: @J.M.: yes, but by definition of cosine integral, not actually evaluating something, like the OP claims.

Comment: @enzotib, maybe OP went further and expressed it in terms of the incomplete gamma function... :D

Comment: @enzotib: In fact, I did try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with $\ \displaystyle f(x):=\log(\tan(x/2))\ $ then :
$$f'(x)=\frac{\tan(x/2)^2+1}{2\tan(x/2)}=\frac{\sin(x/2)^2+\cos(x/2)^2}{2\cos(x/2)^2\tan(x/2)}=\frac 1{\sin(x)}$$

so that $\ f'\left(t+\frac {\pi}2\right)=\dfrac 1{\cos(t)}$.

We want (ignoring integration constants up to the end) :
$$\int \dfrac t{\cos(t)}\,dt=\int tf'\left(t+\frac {\pi}2\right) dt=\left[tf\left(t+\frac {\pi}2\right)\right]-\int f\left(t+\frac {\pi}2\right)\,dt$$
Setting $\ u:=\tan\bigl(\frac x2\bigr)\ $ so that $\ dx=\dfrac {2\;du}{1+u^2}$ we rewrite the integral of $f$ as :
$$\int f(x)\;dx=\int \log\left(\tan\left(\frac x2\right)\right)\;dx=2\int \frac{\log(u)}{1+u^2}\;du$$
$$=\left[2\log(u)\arctan(u)\right]-2\int \frac {\arctan(u)}u\,du=2\left[\log(u)\arctan(u)-\rm{Ti}_2(u)\right]$$ with $\rm{Ti}_2$ the [inverse tangent integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html) proposed by J.M. (see Lewin 1981 "Polylogarithms and associated functions" ch. 2 for more information). $\rm{Ti}_2$ may be rewritten as [Clausen functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function) or as complex [polylogarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

We want $\ \int f\bigl(t+\frac {\pi}2\bigr)\,dt\ $ so that $\ u:=\tan\bigl(\frac t2+\frac {\pi}4\bigr)\ $ 
and 
$$\int f\left(t+\frac {\pi}2\right)\,dt=2\left[\log\left(\tan\left(\frac t2+\frac {\pi}4\right)\right)\left(\frac t2+\frac {\pi}4\right)-\rm{Ti}_2\left(\tan\left(\frac t2+\frac {\pi}4\right)\right)\right]$$

getting :
$$\int \dfrac t{\cos(t)}\,dt=t\left[\log\left(\tan\left(\frac t2+\frac {\pi}4\right)\right)\right]-2\left[\log\left(\tan\left(\frac t2+\frac {\pi}4\right)\right)\left(\frac t2+\frac {\pi}4\right)-\rm{Ti}_2\left(\tan\left(\frac t2+\frac {\pi}4\right)\right)\right]$$

and finally :
$$\int_0^t \dfrac x{\cos(x)}\,dx=-\frac {\pi}2\log\left(\tan\left(\frac t2+\frac {\pi}4\right)\right)+2\rm{Ti}_2\left(\tan\left(\frac t2+\frac {\pi}4\right)\right)+C$$
where the additional constant $\ C=-2\;\rm{Ti}_2(1)=-2K\quad$ ($K$ is the [Catalan constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant)).

To rewrite this with Clausen functions we may use (4.31) of Lewin's reference :
$$\rm{Ti}_2(\tan \theta)=\theta\log(\tan\theta)+\frac 12\left(\rm{Cl}_2(2\theta)-\rm{Cl}_2(\pi-2\theta)\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for following through, again. :) I had forgotten about the Clausen function... good thing you mentioned it too, for the benefit of those who want to avoid using complex numbers in real results.

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni: Clausen functions? I didn't know they have a name. :-) Thanks.

Comment: @Chris'sister: Glad you liked my 'all real' solution ! Clausen functions are indeed interesting since you may write them as $\displaystyle \rm{Cl}_{2n}(\theta)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\sin(n\theta)}{n^{2n}}$ and $\displaystyle \rm{Cl}_{2n+1}(\theta)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\cos(n\theta)}{n^{2n+1}}$as found at [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClausenFunction.html) (I think that wikipedia's ['General definition'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#General_definition) should rather be something like ...

Comment: $\displaystyle \rm{Cl}_s(\theta)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\sin(n\theta+s\pi/2)}{n^s}$ if we accept to change some signs !). These series are frequent in Fourier series and the other half of the cases is handled by the [Bernoulli polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Fourier_series).

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni: I usually like the solutions from which I have something to learn as this solution is.

Comment: Thanks @J.M. ! Playing with B.B.P. identities some years earlier Clausen functions appeared quite often. They were related to [Log Sine Integrals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogSineFunction.html) and [central binomial series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralBinomialCoefficient.html),

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni: anytime you have a solution and you're willing to share it I'm there glad to receive it.

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$
\frac{1}{\cos t}=
\frac{2}{e^{it}+e^{-it}}=
\frac{2e^{it}}{1+e^{2it}}
$$
so integration by parts gives
$$
\int\frac{t}{\cos t}dt=
\int 2t\frac{e^{it}}{1+e^{2it}}dt=
\int 2t\frac{(-i)d(e^{it})}{1+e^{2it}}=
\int -2itd(\arctan(e^{it}))=
$$
$$
-2it\arctan(e^{it})-\int\arctan(e^{it})d(-2it)=
-2it\arctan(e^{it})+2i\int\arctan(e^{it})dt
$$
It is remains to compute the last integral
$$
\int\arctan(e^{it})dt=
\int\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(e^{it})^{2k+1}}{2k+1}dt=
\int\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(ie^{it})^{2k+1}}{i(2k+1)}dt=
\int\frac{1}{2i}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(ie^{it})^k}{k}-
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-ie^{it})^k}{k}\right)dt=
\frac{1}{2i}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\int\frac{(ie^{it})^k}{k}dt-
\frac{1}{2i}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\int\frac{(-ie^{it})^k}{k}dt=
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2i}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(ie^{it})^k}{ik^2}-
\frac{1}{2i}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-ie^{it})^k}{ik^2}=
\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathrm{Li}_2(-ie^{it})-\mathrm{Li}_2(ie^{it})\right)
$$
The final result is
$$
\int\frac{t}{\cos t}=-2it\arctan(e^{it})+i(\mathrm{Li}_2(-ie^{it})-\mathrm{Li}_2(ie^{it}))
$$

Comment: As I've already noted, one might choose to use the [inverse tangent integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html) instead of the dilogarithm in this case...

Comment: I saw your comment after I finished writing this answer

Comment: I like all your provided answers. (+1)

Comment: Thanks @Chris'sister, glad to see nice questions

Answer (score 0):

Letting $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-t$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}\int \frac{t}{\cos t} d t&=-\int \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}{\sin x} d x \\
& =-\frac{\pi}{2} \int \csc x d x+\int \frac{x}{\sin x} d x \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2} \ln \left|\csc x+\cot x\right|+ x \ln \left(\frac{1-e^{i x}}{1+e^{ix}}\right) +i\left[\operatorname{Li_2}\left(-e^{i x}\right)-\operatorname{Li_2}\left(e^{i x}\right)\right]+C  \\&= \frac{\pi}{2} \ln |\sec t+\tan t|+\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right) \ln \left(\frac{1-i e^{-it}}{1+i e^{-it}}\right)+i\left[\operatorname{Li_2}\left(-i e^{-it}\right)-\operatorname{Li_2}\left(i e^{-it}\right)\right]+C
\end{aligned}
$$

the last integral refers to the result of  my [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4728014/732917),
$$\int \frac{x}{\sin x} d x =x \ln \left(\frac{1-e^{i x}}{1+e^{ix}}\right) +i\left[\operatorname{Li_2}\left(-e^{i x}\right)-\operatorname{Li_2}\left(e^{i x}\right)\right]+C 
$$