# Calculate the indefinite integral $\int \frac{x}{\sin x}\,{\rm d}x$

Tags: integration

I have to calculate this integral $\int \frac{x}{\sin x}\,{\rm d}x$.
Is there any way to evaluate this?

Thanks.

Comment: Wolframalpha shows one in terms of the polylogarithm function

Comment: The key idea is to use a substitution $e^{ix}=z$. The resulting integral is easily expressed in terms of dilogarithms after performing an integration by parts.

Answer (score 2):

This function's primitive is not expressable in terms of elementary functions. Basically, you're integrating $\frac{1}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}$

See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) for a detailed explanation

Comment: I'm sorry, what?

Answer (score 2):

This integral doesn't have a closed-form solution.

See here [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bx%2FSin%5Bx%5D%2C%20x%5D)

Comment: How can I recognize this type of integrals ?

Comment: @NirMovshovitz If you really want to do so, you should keep several kinds of special integral in mind. However, in my opinion,wasting your time on that is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

The integrand does not admit a closed form antiderivative. See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for more information. However, its definite counterpart evaluated over $\bigg(0,~\dfrac\pi2\bigg)$ yields twice the value of [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant) as a result.

Answer (score 2):

The integral is not elementary but can be expressed in terms of dilogarithm function as

$$\boxed{\int \frac{x}{\sin x} d x =x \ln \left(\frac{1-e^{i x}}{1+e^{i x}}\right) +i\left[\operatorname{Li_2}\left(-e^{i x}\right)-\operatorname{Li_2}\left(e^{i x}\right)\right]+C \;}
$$

By complex number, we transform the integral into
$$
\int \frac{x}{\sin x} d x=2 i \int \frac{x}{e^{i x}-e^{-i x}} d x= 2 i \int \frac{x e^{i x}}{e^{2 i x}-1} d x
$$
Using integration by parts, we have
$$
\int \frac{x}{\sin x} d x =\int x \, d \left(\ln \left(\frac{1-e^{i x}}{1+e^{i x}}\right)\right) =x \ln \left(\frac{1-e^{i x}}{1+e^{i x}}\right)-\int \ln \left(\frac{1-e^{i x}}{1+e^{i x}}\right)d x
$$
For the last integral,
$$
\int \ln \left(1-e^{i x}\right) d x \stackrel{y=e^{ix}}{=}  \int \frac{\ln (1-y)}{-i y} d y= i \operatorname{Li_2}\left(y\right) =i \operatorname{Li_2}\left(e^{i x}\right)+C_1
$$
Similarly,
$$
\int \ln \left(1+e^{i x}\right) d x \stackrel{z=-e^{ix}}{=}  \int \frac{\ln (1-z)}{i z} d z
=-i \operatorname{Li_2}\left(z\right)
=-i \operatorname{Li_2}\left(-e^{i x}\right)+C_2
$$
Now we can conclude that
$$\int \frac{x}{\sin x} d x =x \ln \left(\frac{1-e^{i x}}{1+e^{ix}}\right) +i\left[\operatorname{Li_2}\left(-e^{i x}\right)-\operatorname{Li_2}\left(e^{i x}\right)\right]+C 
$$