# A question about integrals of the form $\int_{0}^{a}\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

Considering integrals of the form

$$\int_{0}^{a}\frac x{\sin(x)}\,dx \quad a\in\mathbb{R}$$

I was wondering when this integral has a closed form expression in terms of special functions if needed, instead of just a numerical approximation.

I already have evaluated it for $\pi\over2$ yielding:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\,dx=2G$$

Where $G$ is Catalans constant.

Anyone know of any else?

Comment: The integral diverges if $a\ge \pi$, so you may try some values at $\pi/4$ or $3\pi/4$

Comment: Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4728014/155629

Comment: @Angelo. Answer deleted. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

From the tables,  there is no closed expression. As all integrals of  functions involving rationals of trignonometrics, by the inversion of the simple $\arctan$ series for the $\tan$, the coefficients are trivial factors of $(-1)^n,  2^n, n!$ and Bernoulli numbers.

$$\int x \ \text{csc}(x) \ dx  = x + 2 \ \sum _{k=1}^n \frac{ (-1)^{k+1} \left(2^{2 k-1}-1\right) \ B_{2 k} } {(2 k+1)!} \  \ x^{2 k+1}$$

Comment: Roland, you answered a duplicate question. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1627544/calculate-the-indefinite-integral-int-fracx-sin-x-rm-dx/4728014#4728014). So you should remove your answer.