# How do I evaluate $\int_{0}^{T}\tanh^{-1}(\sin(x))dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following integral,

$$\int_{0}^{T}\tanh^{-1}(\sin(x))dx.$$

I have tried writing $\tanh^{-1}(\sin(x))$ as a series and solving the resultant $\sin^n(x)$ integrals using a recursion formula. I have also tried substituting $\sin(x)=u$. But I am not getting anywhere. Part of my problem is that I am not sure that the integral has a solution and I am not sure how to test this.

Note that I am not a mathematician, nor especially mathematically literate. This came up in a research project and I now have another approach which doesn't use this integral. I just want to know it this integral is soluble, and if so, how? It would also be useful to check my other method using this method.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. [You might need](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+artanh%28sin+x%29&dataset=) [dilogarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilogarithm).

Comment: Thanks! I tried Wolfram but it threw a couple of cogs and gave up. I'll try that again.

Comment: It might have thought your $\tanh^{-1}$ meant $\coth$.

Comment: N.b. the integrand satisfies $\operatorname{artanh} \sin 0 = 0$ and $\frac{d}{dx} \operatorname{artanh} \sin x = \sec x$, so the integrand is the *anti-Gudermannian* or *Lambertian* function, $\operatorname{gd}^{-1} x$, which appears, e.g., in the construction of the Mercator projection. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function

Comment: @TravisWillse Tags should be used to indicate what the question is *about*, at the level of the *asker*.  They should not be used (generally speaking) to indicate which tools an outside expert feels might be relevant---adding more sophisticated tags can influence the way in which answerers reply.  In this case, I think that the [tag:polylogarithm] tag is inappropriate (though the asker is free to disagree and add the tag themselves, if they feel that such a tag makes sense to them).

Answer (score 3):

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%20of%20atanh%28sin%28x%29%29) gives the indefinite integral of your expression as

$$\int \tanh^{-1}(\sin(x)) dx = -i \mathrm{Li}_2(-i e^{i x}) + i \mathrm{Li}_2(i e^{i x}) \\ + x (-\log(1 - i e^{i x}) + \log(1 + i e^{i x}) + \tanh^{-1}(\sin(x))) + c$$

where $\mathrm{Li}_2$ is the [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) of order 2. This might not be particularly satisfying, but it's also possibly the best that we can do.

Note that the integrand has discontinuities, so you need to be careful if your value of $T$ is greater than $\frac{\pi}{2}$. On that note, however, we can find some specific values of the integral, for example if $T = \frac{\pi}{2}$ then the value is [2C](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%20of%20atanh%28sin%28x%29%29%20from%200%20to%20pi%2F2), where $C$ is [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

If you wanted to find the integral by hand, then it would probably involve application of some combination of the following:

- Using the identity $\tanh^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{2}(\ln(1+u) - \ln(1-u))$
- Using the identity $\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$
- Integration by parts, particularly via $\int 1 \cdot f(x) dx = x f(x) - \int x f'(x) dx$

Answer (score 2):

There is no closed form in terms of elementary functions, but we can proceed as follows. First, note that the integrand satisfies
$$\frac{d}{dx} \operatorname{artanh} \sin x = \sec x$$
---in fact, $\operatorname{artanh} \sin$ is the [*anti-Gudermannian* or *Lambertian* function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function), $\operatorname{gd}^{-1} x = \int_0^x \sec t \,dt$, which appears, e.g., in the construction of the Mercator projection. So, integrating by parts, taking $u = \operatorname{artanh} \sin x$, $dv = dx$, gives
$$\int_0^T \operatorname{artanh} \sin x \,dx = T \operatorname{artanh} \sin T - \int_0^T x \sec x \,dx .$$
Per the answers to [this question about the latter integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182071/evaluating-int-fract-cost-dt), this expression has value
$$\boxed{\int_0^T \operatorname{artanh} \sin x \,dx = T \operatorname{artanh} \sin T + i(\operatorname{Li}_2(ie^{i T})-\operatorname{Li}_2(-ie^{i T}))+ 2 T \arctan (i e^{i T}) + 2 G} ,$$
where $\operatorname{Li}_2$ is the [dilogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilogarithm) and $G$ is [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant). The particular value $T = \frac\pi2$ gives the pleasant identity $\int_0^\frac\pi2 \operatorname{artanh} \sin x \,dx = 2 G$.

Comment: Thank you, this is fabulous! I will need to read up on these functions and constants.

Answer (score 1):

Via integration by parts, we have

$$
\begin{aligned} \int_0^T \tanh ^{-1}(\sin x) d x 
= & {[x \tanh (\sin x)]_0^T-\int_0^T \frac{x \cos x}{1-\sin ^2 x} \cdot d x } \\
= & T \tanh ^{-1}(\sin T)-\int_0^T \frac{x}{\cos x} d x
\end{aligned}
$$

Plugging the result in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/182106/732917)
$$
\int\frac{t}{\cos t} \,dt=-2it\arctan(e^{it})+i(\mathrm{Li}_2(-ie^{it})-\mathrm{Li}_2(ie^{it}))
$$
into our integral, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
I= & T \tanh ^{-1}(\sin T)-\left[-2 i x \arctan \left(e^{i x}\right) +i\left(\mathrm{Li}_2\left(-i e^{i x}\right)-\mathrm{Li}_2\left(i e^{i x}\right)\right)\right]_0^{\top} \\
= & T \tanh ^{-1}(\sin T)+2 i T \arctan \left(e^{i T}\right)+i\left[\mathrm{Li}_2\left(-i e^{i T}\right)-\mathrm{Li}_2\left(i e^{i T}\right)\right] -i\left[L_{i_2}(-i)-L_{i_2}(i)\right] \\
= & T \tanh ^{-1}(\sin T)+2 i T \arctan \left(e^{i T}\right)+i\left[\mathrm{Li}_2\left(-i e^{i T}\right)-\mathrm{Li}_2\left(i e^{i T}\right)\right] +2 G
\end{aligned} 
$$
where $\mathrm{Li}_2(.)$ is the dilogarithm function and $G$ is the Catalan constant.

Comment: Thank you very much!